# Error in pom.xml file

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-3

I am using Maven 3.0.4 along with the Eclipse Indigo for an Android Project. But i am not able to compile my code as there are errors in pom.xml file.

Errors are :

```
Project build error: Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.0.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:jar:3.0.2 ()


Project build error: Unknown packaging: apk
```

I have downloaded the Android configurator plugin from Eclipse MarketPlace.

Unable to find the way out. Any help regarding this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please add the complete maven output and the command you run.

Comment: And/or in Eclipse, turn on Debug Output in the Preferences | Maven section.

Comment: Please include your pom.xml.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run this from the console?

Comment: Have you run the build on the commandline to download the android-maven-plugin into your local repository?

Comment: The errors were because of the google maps jar which had not got downloaded from the repository. Downloaded the same externally and placed in the respective folder solved the issue. Thanks for the response.